# VkScript метод execute

Tags: vknet, vkscript

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему в данном запросе возвращает только 1000 участников, хотя должно 25000

```
    ExecuteCategory ex = new ExecuteCategory(user);

    var check = ex.Execute(@"
var members = API.groups.getMembers({"group_id": "57846937", "v": "5.131", "sort": "id_asc", "count": "1000", "offset": Args.offset}).items; // делаем первый запрос и создаем массив
var offset = 1000; // это сдвиг по участникам группы
while (offset < 25000 && (offset + Args.offset) < Args.total_count) // пока не получили 20000 и не прошлись по всем участникам
{
  members = members + "," + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id": 57846937, "v": "5.131", "sort": "id_asc", "count": "1000", "offset": (Args.offset + offset)}).items; // сдвиг участников на offset + мощность массива
  offset = offset + 1000; // увеличиваем сдвиг на 1000
};
return members;
");

    Console.WriteLine(check.RawJson);
```

Буду благодарен любой вашей помощи, заранее спасибо

Comment: А почему у вас в первом getMembers подставлен конкретный group_id, а во втором getMembers вместо него используется Args.group_id?

Comment: Моя ошибка, поправил, но всё равно выдаёт 1000 участников за 1 запрос

Comment: В условии while стоят Args.offset и Args.total_count — они прописаны где-нибудь? В показанном здесь коде как-то не вижу, чтобы их значения задавались

Comment: Точно! Нашёл ошибку, убрал из while (offset + Args.offset) < Args.total_count и всё возвращает как нужно.  andreymal - спасибо вам большущее!